# Localization in ASP .NET MVC 5 web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I need to localize validation messages (Like ... field is required) to Slovak language? I have found many solutions using Resources files (e.g. http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx). Is there any better way to do this? I don´t need globalization (language based on user browser culture), my only need is to localize validation messages to Slovak.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: not alot to go off of here, how are you popping up these messages? do you need to always translate to slovak or sometimes yes sometimes no?

Comment: All the time. In fact, all messages in english should be only in Slovak

Comment: is this a permanent change? where are the messages currently store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can try this for standardized localizations](https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n)